# Avalonia DataGrid объединить ячейки в шапке таблицы

Tags: avalonia

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте! Хочу сделать шапку таблицы, как показано на фото, т.е. шапка состоит из 8 столбцов и 2 строк, нужно объединить некоторые ячейки. Подскажите, как можно добиться такого результата

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Переведите вопрос или задайте его на enSO.

Comment: Скажу честно, такого нет в WPF (а авалония это WPF), довольно часто видел тут подобный вопрос, но люди так и не получали ответ. Чтобы такое реализовать, нужно писать свой собственный контрол, со своим собственным поведением. Альтернатива - использовать костыли, по типу `Grid`, внутри которого будут нужные заголовки, с указанием `Grid.RowSpan` и `Grid.ColumnSpan`, который позволяет задать сколько клеток будет занимать элемент, вот так костыльно, делаете "вид", а уже затем выводите остальные элементы.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, тоже пришел к такому решению. Похоже, оно единственное, поскольку DataGrid в Avalonia ведет себя максимально непредсказуемо.